# Convert bytes to signed integers in lua 5.1.5

Tags: lua, type-conversion

I'm looking for how to turn bytes into a signed int using lua 5.1.5, so far I've only been able to find solutions for lua 5.2 onward, and they are not backward compatible.

I have solutions for how to turn bytes into unsigned integers, like so:

```
payload_t.temperature=tonumber(utility.hex2str(string.sub(payload,32,33)),16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'll assume that you actually have a **byte string** rather than a **hex string** given; if your string is a hex string, you can trivially convert it to a byte string using `gsub`:

```lua
function hex2bytes(str)
     -- assert that it is indeed a string of hex digit pairs
    assert(#str % 2 == 0 and not str:match"[^%x]")
    return str:gsub("%x%x", function(hex) return tonumber(hex, 16) end)
end
```

Now, let's convert this byte string to an integer. I'll assume little endian (least significant byte first); should your string be big endian (most significant byte first) you'll have to reverse it using `str:reverse()` before you read it.

Reading an unsigned integer is pretty straightforward:

```lua
function bytes2uint(str)
    local uint = 0
    for i = 1, #str do
        uint = uint + str:byte(i) * 0x100^(i-1)
    end
    return uint
end
```

I'll assume your integers are stored using [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). In this case the higher 2^n values (equivalent to the first bit being set or the value being >= 2^(n-1)) the uint can take represent negative numbers, with the smallest value (2^(n-1)) representing the largest negative value (-2^(n-1)). Thus you can simply subtract the unsigned value from 2^n, the (exclusive) max value for the uint:

```
function bytes2int(str)
    local uint = bytes2uint(str)
    local max = 0x100 ^ #str
    if uint >= max / 2 then
        return uint - max
    end
    return uint
end
```